# Why does this JQuery not transition?

Tags: html, css, jquery-ui, jquery

http://jsfiddle.net/kCMvt/

Hey everyone. I made this jQuery page for a mobile phone, but the transitions are just not working correctly and I  thought I had done everything correctly. I pretty much looked at the code from another example and used the same one, but not sure why it doesn't transition. There's A LOT of CSS because I got this from the jQuery theme roller so that is why it is kinda excessive. I'm not too much of a jQuery expert enough (yet) to do my own stuff, but I cna't image it is actually that complicated come to think of it.

This HTML doesn't transition:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

    <head>

        <meta charset="utf-8">

        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <title>jQuery Mobile: Theme Download</title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="themes/test1.min.css" />

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.1/jquery.mobile.structure-1.1.1.min.css" />

        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>

        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.1/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.js"></script>

    </head>

    <body>

        <div data-role="page" data-theme="a">

            <div data-role="header" data-position="inline">

            <div>

                <h1 style="font-size:16px;text-align:center;">Random Question</h1>

                </div>

            </div>

            <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">



                <input type="radio" name="radiochoice" id="radio-choice-1" value="choice-1" checked="checked" />

                <a href="#page2"><label for="radio-choice-1">Yes</label></a>



                <input type="radio" name="radio-choice" id="radio-choice-2" value="choice-2" />

                <a href="#page2"><label for="radio-choice-2">No</label></a>

            </fieldset>

            <div data-role="content" data-theme="a">

                <p style="text-align:center;font-weight:bold;color:#003366;">blablablab bla</p>

            </div><!-- end content -->







          <div data-role="footer">

          <h4>cool footer</h4> 



        </div><!-- end page -->



 <!-- start of 2nd page -->

 <div data-role="page" id="page2">



 <div data-role="header">

     <h1>Thanks For Your Opinion!</h1>

 </div><!-- end header -->



 <div data-role="content">

     <p>Page Content</p>

 </div>



 <div data-role="footer">

     <h4>Copyright</h4>

    </div><!-- end footer -->

 </div><!-- end page -->   



    </body>

</html>​
```

Comment: There's no script in the fiddle you posted

Comment: are you sure? its working for me...

Comment: Make sure you hit the Update button on jsfiddle to save your most recent.

Comment: okay, i just hit update on it. is it working now for you?

Comment: why you don't have any "ui-" class in html?

Comment: i have no idea man.. what does that mean? should be added to the HTML answers? what does that class do?

Comment: i think those classes actualy controls all framework. you just copyied example codes, did you? :) open page with radio buttons and inspect those elements.

Comment: actualy, i see that classes are added dinamically, you don't need to input them manually. Sorry.

Comment: this is update of your fiddle, but still missing bullet inside radio button. http://jsfiddle.net/kCMvt/3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For starters, you are missing an end tag for the first footer (or page):

```
   <div data-role="footer">
      <h4>cool footer</h4>
    </div>
  </div><!-- end page -->
```

Then, you could wrap the entire input, not just the label, in a link:

```
    <a href="#page2">
        <input type="radio" name="radiochoice" id="radio-choice-1" value="choice-1" checked="checked" /> 
        <label for="radio-choice-1">Yes</label>
    </a>
    <a href="#page2">
        <input type="radio" name="radio-choice" id="radio-choice-2" value="choice-2" />
        <label for="radio-choice-2">No</label>
    </a>
```

[Here is a working jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kCMvt/6/)

Also, you should consider posting more well formatted code. Proper indentation would have made the missing tag easier to spot, and you make it more difficult for those trying to read your code when it's formatted as you have it.